# Django import module: Unable to import module by name

Tags: python, django

I have sub-directories inside my django app folder, and on each I was trying to call a module. The issue that I am having is that I am able to import a module by using * but not by name which produces an error "Exception Value: cannot import name [my module]"

```
from foo import Bar # throws error
from foo import * # works
```

I dont know if I am missing anything on my settings.py but definitely I have included the app directory on my INSTALLED_APPS and also I have **init**.py on each directory. I also tried to check if my app folder is included on python paths and it was included.

Any help will be appreciated. THanks in advance

Comment: Are you positive Bar exists? (Caps and all)

Comment: Also, are you attempting to import from manage.py shell? or from python? Or is this error being returned from django when you load the view/page.

Comment: -1 : Question was poorly constructed.

Comment: @moreisee "Are you positive Bar exists?" Yes, infact I am able to use all functions and classes inside the module if I call it by "*".

Comment: @moreisee "Also, are you attempting to import from manage.py shell? or from python? " Im running the code using the builtin django web server

Comment: @karthikr "what is the error ?" . The error it produced is ""Exception Value: cannot import name [my module]" "

Comment: Ok. you need to do `from foo.<filename> import Bar`

Comment: @karthikr Bar is actually the file that contains different classes and functions. so on my codes that uses the module it is like x =Bar.myfunc() also my real issue is why I cant import by name but it works using "*"

Answer (score 2):

I expect you are thinking in terms of Java. In Python, you import things by module, not class name. So if a directory `foo` contains a file `bar.py` which defines a class `Bar`, you must do `from foo.bar import Bar`, *not* `from foo import Bar`.

Answer (score 0):

After looking over my directories I found out that I have a file that has the same name as my app/Foo. after removing this it started working.

```
Foo/
 - Bar.py
Process/
 - Foo.py # deleted this
 - views.py
```

from Foo import Bar #Foo.py was overriding the app/Foo that I was trying to call

Thanks for all your response!

Answer (score 0):

if this is in django, try doing 
from . import form
from . import models
from . import views

This should solve the issue.
Apart from that, fist make sure you have a **init**.py file in the directory.